# Tzedakah Protects from hell?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, gehinnom

I’ve heard rabbis like Rabbi Yosef Mizrachi and Rabbi Yaron Reuven say that giving to a Yeshiva, kiruv, Shule, charity, helps one gain protection from hell or gain mitzvot.

Is there any source for this in Judaism?

Comment: I don't know about hell, but famously, Mishlei (Proverbs) says "צדקה תציל ממות" - charity saves one from death...

Comment: [link](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.10.2?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)

Comment: [Gittin 7a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.7a.21?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi)

Comment: [וצדקה תציל ממוות" - מדינה של גיהנם"](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Mishlei.11.1?vhe=%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_-_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A8&lang=bi)

Comment: [תַּנְיָא הָיָה רַבִּי מֵאִיר אוֹמֵר יֵשׁ לוֹ לְבַעַל הַדִּין לַהֲשִׁיבְךָ וְלוֹמַר לְךָ אִם אֱלֹהֵיכֶם אוֹהֵב עֲנִיִּים הוּא מִפְּנֵי מָה אֵינוֹ מְפַרְנְסָן אֱמוֹר לוֹ כְּדֵי שֶׁנִּיצּוֹל אָנוּ בָּהֶן מִדִּינָהּ שֶׁל גֵּיהִנָּם - Bava_Batra.10a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.10a.2?lang=bi)

Comment: @user813801 and... and this is the where the Internet pundits cited above miss the boat ... Maimonides says that many, many such quotes were hyperbole.

Comment: That’s kind of the same, thank you